# Why there are 12-14 similar SSID around my place

Tags: wireless-networking

Usually there are only 3-5 WiFi network around my place. Yesterday I found suddenly there are 12-14 WiFi station with similar name appeared. The SSIDs look like ED1ECB19, ED1ECC27, ED1EDB16...

Has anyone seen this before? How can I get more information to see if these are all from same AP (maybe an advanced one that can have several AP in one box)? Or this is from ISP or whatever.

Comment: I guess it's the default SSID of the modem router from the ISP and they haven't rename it. It happens to me too.  check this out http://i.stack.imgur.com/zB0Nk.png

Comment: I know 2WIRExxx is at&t wireless router. Usually each at&t ADSL only has one AP and one SSID. In my case, these similar SSIDs show up at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

The comment is correct.  ISPs that deliver a wireless router as part of their service tend to auto-generate the SSID.

So if you are in an area with limited ISP options it is common to see similar SSIDs nearby.

Note that some ISPs do not do this particularly well, and generate the Pre-Shared-Key with a similar algorithm, and in cases in such a way that the key can be derived from the SSID fairly easily.

Always change the SSID and key from default, no matter what the source of your router.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a Windows computer with a compatable WiFi card, [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/) from metageek is a free program that will tell you all sorts of useful information about wireless networks it can see.  It will often be able to tell you the manufacturer and model of the device.  I mainly use it to find the quietest channel to use for my WiFi.